# Interesting Effect used on AIGA website

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://celebratedesign.org/connect Browsing through sites I came across this page that has an interesting affect that I want to try on my own website. When the user scrolls down there is a diagonal slicing effect that goes across the page. I can't seem to access the affect through developer tools on any browser I use I have no idea what to call it when googling. Does anyone know what this effect is called and how it was implemented in the code? Is it a plugin or is it just an animation? Please let me know if I need to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a plugin, that appears to be animated svg, possibly canvas.